# teradata sql pivot multiple occurrences into additional columns

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata

I have something like this:

```
ID      Result
1       value1
2       value1
2       value2
3       value1
4       value1
4       value2
4       value3
```

And I'd like to return something like this:

```
ID      Result1      Result2      Result3
1       value1
2       value1       value2
3       value1
4       value1       value2       value3
```

I've searched on pivots and concats and breaks and I just can't find a simple, sensible solution.

TIA

Comment: Are you going to have a limited number of results for each id?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Each ID may or may not have additional results, but no more than about 10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately Teradata doesn't have a PIVOT function but you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result.

```
select id,
    max(case when seq =1 then result end) result1,
    max(case when seq =2 then result end) result2,
    max(case when seq =3 then result end) result3
from
(
    select id, res, row_number() over(partition by id order by result) seq
    from yourtable
) d
group by id
order by id;
```

If you have more values for each ID, then you can add more CASE expressions.

Comment: bluefeet, what if some of the numbered rows have the same value? Is there a way in this method to disregard them if they are duplicate values?

Comment: @user2820576 I would suggest that you Ask a new question with the new details and requirements