# Accomplish pivot in teradata sql

Tags: teradata

Say I have a query that returns values like this:

```
id    type     value
aaa   1a        10
aaa   1b        20
aaa   1c        7
bbb   2a        10
bbb   1a        5
```

There are > 50 million rows and 240 possible "types".  I want to make a pivot where there is one row for each `id` and each `type` is it's own column:

```
id   1a   1b   1c   2a
aaa  10   20   7    
bbb  5              10
```

I can do this in SQL server but I don't know how to do it in Teradata.  There are too many columns for me to make CASE statements.  However, each distinct `type` is in a table field, if that's any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no pivot function in Teradata SQL. A similar question was answered here - [teradata sql pivot multiple occurrences into additional columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035081/teradata-sql-pivot-multiple-occurrences-into-additional-columns).

To best achieve what you wanted without having to write out 250 cases manually, you should use ordered analytical functions in some kind of a loop or a set. Try searching "loop" tag from Teradata Developer Exchange - http://developer.teradata.com/tag/loop

Here's how I would do it: Use another programming language (Python) to reiterate over a text/premade SQL and change it's only two variables 250 times, from 1 to 250, and generate the full long sql. Only reiterate the part between `SELECT DISTINCT id` and last `FROM mytable` row:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
id
-- reiteration starts here
,(SELECT SUM(value) -- assuming you have unique types for every id
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    id
    ,value
    ,type
    FROM mytable
    QUALIFY (RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id ASC))=1 -- variable 1
    )
) AS type_1 -- variable 2
-- reiteration ends here
FROM mytable
```

You can use this python:

```py
for i in range(1,251):
    print " \
,(SELECT SUM(value) -- assuming you have unique types for every id \
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT \
id \
,value \
,type \
FROM mytable \
QUALIFY (RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY id ASC))=%d -- variable 1 \
) \
) AS type_%d -- variable 2 \
" % (i,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a TD_UNPIVOT function which was added in TD 14.10 can be found in TD_SYSFNLIB.

[TD_UNPIVOT Function](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/Table_Operators.098.23.html#ww14542022)

The PIVOT and UNPIVOT SQL commands were added in Teradata 16 and they can be found in the SQL Functions, Operators, Expressions, and Predicates manual. At this time, I can't find them in an online manual so you will need to download the PDF from Teradata.com.

[New TD 16 Features PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035-1098-160K/rnz1472240714147.html)

Comment: Both functions can be found online in the *Functions and Operators*, chapter *Aggregate Functions*: http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/vpq1472240905673.html#

Answer (score 1):

Pivot functionality has been added at least as far back as v16.1:

[https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GnnbigJTnAWrDfLbecAN7Q](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/GnnbigJTnAWrDfLbecAN7Q)

Providing some examples for this answer.

v16.2 and newer allows for you to select distinct values from a table in your pivot, where as 16.1 you will need to specify the fields to pivot on. Both examples provided below.

DDL to create sample table:

```sql
Create table tbl(id varchar(3), typ varchar(2), val smallint);
insert into  tbl ('aaa',   '1a',  10);
insert into  tbl ('aaa',   '1b',  20);
insert into  tbl ('aaa',   '1c',  7);
insert into  tbl ('bbb',   '2a',  10);
insert into  tbl ('bbb',   '1a',  5);
```

In 16.1 you MUST specify fields to pivot (note double quotes to convert type names into valid column name):

```sql
Select *
from tbl pivot (sum(val)
                for typ in ('1a' as "1a" ,'1b' as "1b",'1c' as "1c",'2a' as "2a" )
    ) tmp
```

16.2 is a little more flexible, eliminating the need to specify pivot fields explicitly:

```sql
SELECT *
from tbl pivot (sum(val)
                for typ in (Select distinct typ from tbl)
    ) tmp
order by 1
```

Both results are the same:

| id | 1a | 1b | 1c | 2a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 10 | 20 | 7 | NULL |
| bbb | 5 | NULL | NULL | 10 |

However, as far as I know -in 16.2 at least-, you can not physicalize results when using a subquery to pivot (e.g. `for typ in (Select Distinct typ from tbl` ) within the pivot operator. This limits dynamically defined pivots to final results sets. You can however create a view, volatile, or physical table from a pivot when you explicitly define the fields (e.g. `for typ in ('1a','1b','1c','2a' )`). Hopefully Teradata will enhance this to include subqueries in the future.

You can pivot using multiple aggregate functions:

```sql
SELECT *
from tbl pivot (sum(val) as "Sum", count(val) as "Count"
                for typ in (Select distinct typ from tbl)
    ) tmp
order by 1
```

| id | 2a_Sum | 1c_Sum | 1a_Sum | 1b_Sum | 2a_Count | 1c_Count | 1a_Count | 1b_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | NULL | 7 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| bbb | 10 | NULL | 5 | NULL | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

There is also an unpivot function that you can use to convert a long table to wide. Thank you @dnoeth for providing the solution in the comments below.

Comment: `for typ in (Select ...` is limited to 16 values and there's no way to sort the columns, both rendering it useless.

Comment: Thanks  @dnoeth for the additional context. I would argue that it can be useful in limited contexts (quick ad hoc queries in smaller scopes), but I would agree that it severely lacking.

Comment: Regarding your problem with UNPIVOT, this works: `SELECT * 
FROM y 
UNPIVOT
 (
   val
   FOR typ IN (a1, b1, c1, a2)
 ) tmp`

Comment: how does the sum() operator work here; even if you put avg() it would give you the same results here right?

Comment: I this example, Avg and sum would return the same thing because there is only one set of values. I.E. AAA 1A = 10 + null (sum) is the same as AAA 1A = 10/1 (avg). If we added a second row in the table as AAA 1A 5, then sum would return 15 (AAA 1A = 10 + 5) and the average function would return 7.5 ( AAA 1A = (10+5)/2) ).

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT function in Teradata 16 it could look like this (assuming your types are in a table called mytypetable):

```sql
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  mytable PIVOT (SUM("value") FOR "type" IN (SELECT "Type" FROM mytypetable)) AS Temp_pivot
ORDER BY 
  id
```

One drawback is that you cannot decide on the order of the columns though.