# Dynamic pivot using ANSI SQL

Tags: teradata, ansi-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have a table test123 where the data like below

```
create table test123
(
id varchar(3),
typ varchar(2),
val int
);

Select * from test123 order by id,typ;

id      typ val
aaa     1a  10
aaa     1b  20
aaa     1c  7
aaa     2a  10
bbb     1a  5
bbb     1d  17
```

**Now I want the output like below using ANSI SQL (which can work in Teradata)**

```
id    1a    1b    1c    1d      2a
aaa   10    20    7     NULL    10
bbb   5     NULL  NULL  17      NULL
```

Now the number of type can change and accordingly there will be more columns for this.

The sql below from the post [Accomplish pivot in teradata sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335854/accomplish-pivot-in-teradata-sql) didn't resolve my question

```
SELECT DISTINCT
id
-- reiteration starts here
,(SELECT SUM(val) -- assuming you have unique types for every id
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    id
    ,val
    ,typ
    FROM test123
    QUALIFY (RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY typ ORDER BY id ASC))=1 -- variable 1
    ) AS type_1
) AS type_2 -- variable 2
-- reiteration ends here
FROM test123
```

I also did tried the python code given in the link [Accomplish pivot in teradata sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335854/accomplish-pivot-in-teradata-sql) but not getting the expected result

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="koushik", passwd="koushik", db="koushik")

cur = db.cursor()

for i in range(1, 251):
    print(" \
,(SELECT SUM(value) -- assuming you have unique types for every id \
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT \
id \
,val \
,typ \
FROM test123 \
QUALIFY (RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY typ ORDER BY id ASC))=%d -- variable 1 \
) \
) AS type_%d -- variable 2 \
" % (i, i))

db.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accomplish pivot in teradata sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335854/accomplish-pivot-in-teradata-sql)

Comment: I am not getting the desired output using the sql from the post you mentioned

Comment: The linked post shows a veeeeery inefficient answer, but it links to another answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19036314/2527905, which shows the Standard SQL way using `MAX(CASE)`. If the number of type can change you must to add/remove CASEes accordingly. The only other solution is a Stored Procedure creating this as a Dynamic SQL statement.